# Standard css fix for all browsers?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I’m getting an overflow module slideshow with IE, and bad display on Firefox, I’ve googled and found here some posts that suggest using meyers or yahoo resets, now I’ve copy/paste the reset meyers codes to a file named css/style.css, but nothing happens (Exactly same display as before).
Then I’ve googled how exactly to reset the css with success, and I’ve read somewhere there is no standard way to do this reset?
I don’t know where else to ask this noob questions...and probably this is not the way or place to ask this either...
Is there a step by step guide on how to reset css on all browsers?
Which file and where this file should be?

Comment: Show us some code. It's hard to tell if you aren't sure how to use a reset stylesheet, or how to use CSS at all!

Answer (score 0):

Reset CSS brings all elements to same look and feel with normalized styles on almost all browsers.

Include any reset CSS in you page and after that start adding your own styles.

Reset CSS minimizes browser incompatibility. But it doesn't remove completely, if we are creating any complex layouts.

I prefer Eric Meyer's Reset CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but im struggling to add this CSS to my page...Where do I add this code? wich path usually is?Ive tried adding to CSS/style.css but nothing happens

Comment: Include "css/style.css" in the head section of HTML page before any style or link tags. Use `<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' media='screen' />`.